# mySQL database hosted connection c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, hosting

Hello and thank you for you time today! I have been trying to research this error and I cannot figure it out thanks for your help.
I have a hosted website with MySQL on it from godaddy. I'm trying to make a connection to the database and receiving this error

> Authentication to host [*my IP is here*] for user[*my user is here*] using method MySQL_native_password failed with message: Access denied for user [my username] @[*some numbers and dashes I didn't add*].in.comcast.net (using password:YES)

```
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "server= [my IP Address is here]; uid=me@whatever.com;pwd=[insert Password here];database=Contacts;";
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("you are now connected");
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Try telnetting, make sure the user exists, make sure the correct firewall port is open, make sure the port is forwarded to the correct IP, man I've spent days figuring this sort of things out. There is, however, not one simple answer to what you've asked. Try to be more specific on what you've tried.

Comment: Thank you Dion, I'll try to telnet. also there isn't much else that I've tried, I didn't know what to try and that is why I googled it. I didn't find much so I read through them tried changing the connection string and then I asked you guys. I will try to telnet and if that doesn't work I'll call godaddy talk to them about their firewall.